# Batch файл запускается и в командной строке Visual Studio Code, и в командной строке Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd, bat, windows-11

Недавно купил ноутбук, перешёл с Windows 10 на 11, установил всякие "программерские штучки" и Visual Studio Code. Я создал файл `newproj.bat`, который автоматизирует создание проекта. Но когда я его открываю, он запускается и в командной строке Visual Studio Code, и в командной строке Windows.
newproj.bat:

```
@echo off

mkdir %1
@REM создаём папку с проектом;

cd %1 
mkdir src
mkdir include
mkdir build
mkdir res
@REM создаём папки src, include, build, res;

NUL > CMakeLists.txt
cd src
NUL > main.cpp 
@REM создаём файлы CMakeLists.txt и main.cpp;

start code main.cpp ..\CMakeLists.txt
@REM запускаем только что созданные файлы в Visual Studio Code;

cd ..\build
@REM переходим в папку build для удобства использования CMake;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На Windows 10 всё работало отлично, и я знаю, что это окно можно закрыть 1 щелчком мыши, но всё же, не хочется делать лишние телодвижение. Как предотвратить появление окна?

Comment: Это из-за вашей команды "start code"

Comment: Я понял это, но почему на 10 винде не было такого?

Comment: Потому что вы не замечали. У меня оно и на 10й винде воспроизводится.

Comment: Мой батник такой же, как и на старом компьютере, возможно он барахлит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это происходит из-за строчки "start code".

Дело в том, что code здесь является пакетным файлом `code.cmd` со следующим содержимым:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set VSCODE_DEV=
set ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1
"%~dp0..\Code.exe" "%~dp0..\resources\app\out\cli.js" --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node %*
endlocal
```

Не знаю я почему создатели VS Code не стали упаковывать её в один исполнимый файл, а сделали пакетный файл для запуска, но получается следующее:

Ваша команда `start code` запускает пакетный файл, этот пакетный файл запускает VS Code и завершает работу, но консольное окно остаётся потому что именно так работает запуск пакетных файлов командой start.

Исправить эту проблему можно заменив команду start на команду call, которая как раз и предназначена для вызова других пакетных файлов в том же окне:

```
call code main.cpp ..\CMakeLists.txt
```

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш вариант помог! Но почему такого не было на 10 винде, загадка...